# selected en select multiple en angular 4

Tags: angular, angular5

como puedo hacer un selected en angular 4 y los datos provenientes son de un json.

mi modelo es

```
export class PvuserTenant{
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public int_user_id: string,
        public int_tenant_id: string,

        public roles_user: Array<any>,
        public user: any,
        public tenant: any
    ){

    }
}
```

el componente que usa esa vista es

```
getUserTenant() {
        this._route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let id = params['id'];
            this.userTenantService.getUserTenant(id).subscribe(
                response => {
                    if (response.code == 200) {
                        this.pvuserTenant = response.data;
                        console.log(this.pvuserTenant);
                    } else {
                        this._router.navigate(['/users-tenant']);
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(<any>error);
                }
            );
        });
    }
```

y la lista de roles es

```
getRoles(){
        this.roleService.getRoles().subscribe(
            result => {

                if(result.code != 200){
                    //console.log(result);
                }else{
                    this.roleModelList = result.data;
                    //console.log(this.roleModelList);
                }
            },
            error => {
                console.log(<any>error);
            }
        );
    }
```

la vista de eso es

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div>Roles</div>
        <select multiple [(ngModel)]="pvuserTenant.roles_user" class="form-control" name="roles" id="roles" 
            required>
            <option *ngFor="let role of roleModelList" value="{{ role.id }}" >
                {{ role.display_name }}  
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

pero no me hace el selected de eso. verificando por consola si trae los datos.

[(ngModel)]="pvuserTenant.roles_user"  es la siguiente imagen donde se ve que si lo trae

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y para llenar los select es

```
<option *ngFor="let role of roleModelList" value="{{ role.id }}" >
```

osea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin embargo esto solo funciona en un select simple, pero en el select multiple no, llevo varios dias tratando con eso y nada que he podido solucionar.

Comment: Creo que debes agregar la propiedad selected =true

Comment: como se debe de agregar. eso no me funciono. Puedes ser mas especifico?

Comment: la unica forma que veo de hacer recorrido es con ng-container o con un elemento html. La verdad no te entiendo bien. Podrias por fa mostrarme el codigo claramente de como se haria? teniendo en base lo que yo mande

Comment: En tu controlador hacer un for a in rolemodellist y hacer a.selected=true algo así

Comment: Igual podrías especificar la librería y la ayuda fuese mejor

Comment: dices hacer el html  en el mismo componente?

Comment: como for (...) if(role.id = a.id) <option selected >? eso es valido en angular? me refiero por el binding. porque intentando tirar selected directamente quemado en el html del componente solo selecciona el ultimo elemento del select multiple

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74930/discussion-between-jacknavarow-and-santiago).